# wgSecureLogin setting

Tags: https, mediawiki, authentication

According to MediaWiki's [Extension:HttpsLogin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HttpsLogin):

> From MediaWiki 1.17, you can redirect all users to HTTPS on login by:
>
> setting `$wgSecureLogin = true;` and
>     setting `$wgServer` as protocol-relative.

However, the page does not tell me whether to set it in ***`LocalSettings.php`*** or ***`DefaultSettings.php`***.

When I check for `$wgSecureLogin`:

```
$ sudo grep -IR "\$wgSecureLogin" /var/www/html/wiki/ | grep Settings
/var/www/html/wiki/includes/DefaultSettings.php:$wgSecureLogin = false;
```

I *thought* Wiki admins were supposed to modify `LocalSettings.php`, and not `DefaultSettings.php`. (I was hoping the search would result in `LocalSettings.php`).

Where should I set `$wgSecureLogin`? Should I modify `DefaultSettings.php`, or should I add a new entry in `LocalSettings.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never modify `DefaultSettings.php`. As its name suggests, it contains defaults; when upgrading your MediaWiki installation, it will be overwritten. Just copy whatever you need to `LocalSettings.php`.